# Should new Linux VMs under ESXi 5.5 mount their filesystems with discard option?

Tags: linux, virtualization, vmware-esxi, storage, trim

When creating new Linux virtual machines using recent (>= 2014) distributions in VMware ESXi 5.5, should they mount their filesystems with the `discard` option ?

I make the assumption that the VM's admin does not necessarily know what is the actual underlying storage and that the VM is using whatever is the recommended "virtual controller" and I hope/suspect that if the VM sends out `TRIM` commands they could be useful with thin virtual disks (even if they are on non-SSD storage) or with thick virtual disks on SSD storage.

Does the `discard` mount option actually do something when used in an ESXi VM (eg. even if the virtual controller is a SCSI one and not a SATA one) ?

Does vSphere >= 5.5 do anything when the VM uses such `discard` option?

Comment: There's no need to do this. Lots of layers of abstraction.

Comment: I'd rather say "it is currently useless to do this"... but if correctly implemented it would really useful (think about freeing thin disk blocks when VM sends out TRIM and/or propagate TRIM to underlying storage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know ESXi doesn't make use of `TRIM` commands from a VM. I havn't found anything definite or official from VMware but in a comment to a blog post I found this:

> In VMs TRIM is definetely not available, I already checked that.

[FAQ: Using SSDs with ESXi](http://www.v-front.de/2013/10/faq-using-ssds-with-esxi.html?showComment=1381089690081#c3653354819100209334)

So it looks like mounting filesystems with the `discard` option won't help you.